# How to get zoom level in IE5 using js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-5

I'm using IE11 and using emulation in developer tool to change document mode to 5. Now I want to get current zoom level, I change it in setting of IE.

[image: ie5 setting]

I'm using this code to get zoom level

```
zoom = document.documentElement.offsetWidth / $(document).width();
```

But it only get zoom out (zoom level <= 100%). If zoom level > 100%, `zoom = 1`.

Comment: yeah I know but my project's requirement need to support this old browser ;)

Comment: Nobody needs to support a browser that doesn't run on any supported operating system. Tell your client they do not need IE 5 support.

Answer (score 2):

there is a library for this:
https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom

Unfortunately, it does not work well currently in Desktop browsers.  But if you look at the code it *might* help.

The short version is that right now this is very difficult. Why are you trying to detect zoom?

Comment: Actually, it's the newer browsers that make it hard.  He'll just have to test.  I'm on a mac so I really can't help there haha.

Answer (score 2):

I found this code in this library seem works for me https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom.

```
var zoom = Math.round((screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI) * 100) / 100;
```

Thanks Rampant for let me know about this library.

Comment: Both [deviceXDPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms533721(v=vs.94)) and [logicalXDPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms534128(v=vs.94)) were introduced in IE6.

Comment: I don't have real IE5 to test this but I when run code in console these XDPI have value

Comment: Well, if it works it works! Just figured I'd give you a heads up. For what it's worth, looks like [Microsoft still provides an IE5 download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53313&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all).